# selecting multiple worksheet with prefix

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, worksheet-function

I am working on a worksheet with multiple tabs although I need to copy data from worksheets that start with only "2018 and 2017".

From these sheets I wanted to copy range -example (A13:L40) and paste them all together in another tab "summary".

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated

Below is the macro I have created so far, still not sure how can i add 2017 as well.

```
Sub Macroif()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Sheets("Summary").Activate

    For Each sheet In Worksheets
        If (sheet.Name Like "2018*") Then
            sheet.Select
            sheet.Range("A13:L40").Copy
            Worksheets("Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

        End If
    Next sheet

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the sheets as well, without selecting the sheet.

```
Sub Macroif()
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> "Summary" Then
            If sh.Name Like "2017*" Or sh.Name Like "2018*" Then
                With sh
                    .Range("A13:L40").Copy
                    With Worksheets("Summary")
                        .Range("A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
                    End With
                End With
            End If

        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: please note, I added a "+1" to the row count

Answer (score -1):

The Sheet object has a property "name", and there are plenty of ways to check for substrings in a string. So simply iterate through all sheets and check if the title begins with your substring, then set a range object to whatever columns you want to copy and copy/paste.

Edit: After OP's edit, here's the missing code:

```
If (sheet.Name Like "2018*") Then
```

Change that to:

```
If (Left(sheet.Name,4)="2018") or (Left(sheet.name,4)="2017") Then
```

Comment: @ComradeMicha thanks a lot, it's working fine. I really appreciate your help.